# Golang, importing packages from Github requests me to remember the Github URL?

Tags: github, go, package

I'm very new to Golang. I see that in Golang you can import packages directly from Github like:

```
import "github.com/MakeNowJust/heredoc"
```

Does that mean I have to remember this URL in order to use this package? IMHO this is not cool. What if later the author of the package removed it or changed the URL? Any ideas?

Comment: You would have the same problem in any other languages if the package author remove their package. You may use tools like [glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) to download & strip vendor package's vcs to push package files to your own repo.

Comment: See also the [wiki entry on package management for Go](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackageManagementTools). Other tools which are on the hype today are (in no particular order): `godep`, `govendor` and `gb`.

Comment: It is actually an interesting question. Maybe not phrased perfectly but it is very much akin to the whole vendoring and dependency management discussion

Comment: Well, you need some way to reference the external dependency. I don't see how it could be simpler than just having the url there 

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I would recommend you to read the [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) documentation and [this](https://blog.golang.org/organizing-go-code) blog post.

The path you're seeing in your import line is not a url, but only the path the package is located in (normally relative to `$GOROOT/src/pkg` or `$GOPATH/src`). So your package `heredoc` is most probably located in the directory `$GOPATH/src/github.com/MakeNowJust/heredoc`.

The recommended way to use external packages is by downloading and installing them via `go get`. You might want to check out the documentation of go get by `go get --help`.

Comment: So this basically says: "No, you cannot import packages directly from Github in Go. Its the tutorial that just makes it sound like that." Correct?

Comment: Yes, you have to download a package to be able to use it.

Comment: github.com/MakeNowJust/heredoc *is* a url and "RTFM" is not a high quality answer that the votes on this would suggest.

Comment: github.com/MakeNowJust/heredo isn't a valid URL - a hostname is present, which implies an absolute URL, but [RFC3986 section 4.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-4.3) specifies that absolute URIs must have a mandatory scheme prefix (http, https, ftp etc.).

Comment: @bain if you can type it into a web browser and it takes you to a web page, it's a valid URL as far as any of us are concerned.

Comment: @steventrouble yes, that is where the confusion lies,but as this answer plainly states, "The path you're seeing in your import line is not a url". Typing something like `/etc/passwd` in your browser location bar works because the browser adds the `file://` prefix. You'll see this if you click in the location bar, or copy/paste the URL. This does not mean that `/etc/passwd` is a valid URL. It's the same with web sites and the `https://` prefix - click in the location bar and copy/paste and you'll see the URL always includes the scheme prefix.

Answer (score 4):

The path that import statement refers is just appended to `$GOPATH/src`. So that import statement basically says "import the package located at `$GOPATH/src/github.com/MakeNowJust/heredoc`"

> What if later the author of the package removed it or changed the URL?

As long as you already have the source files for that package at the expected location, it should be included even if the repo has moved.

Answer (score 0):

dont worry man! you can use [glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) tool for package management

Comment: Glilde is deprecated, use `go dep` for package management instead. For this question you don't need it though.

Comment: go dep was the correct answer, but now it is replaced by mod
https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/introduction.html
https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-download